# How to open SD card folder in Android AVD?

Tags: android, motorola

i have the Motorola MB860 SDK addon for 2.3 in my addons directory of Android SDK. I created a AVD to emulate Atrix hardware using that.

Now my application creates a folder in the SD card's root directory. I installed the application to run on the emulator. The application installed fine, but i don't know how to navigate and open the SD folder. Could someone help me out?

Yes during creation of AVD, i specified the SD card size to be 1 GB, also when the emulator came up, it said preparing SD card, but i don't see any "Files" app as in phone to open the SD card folder.

EDIT - Found it - i got access to Terminal Emulator in Developer Tools/

EDIT - Update - Please someone tell me how to delete the folder in sdcard ?? i got to Terminal Emulator and do rm -r  it says permission not found. I do "su" and it says the user does not have the permission? How do i do that

In DDMS how to delete  the directory

Update - Question is resolved

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb.exe shell rm -r /mnt/sdcard/<directoryname>
```

fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, you can open up File Explorer by going to Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> File Explorer

Comment: how to delete the folder in sdcard ?? i got to Terminal Emulator and do rm -r <directoryName> it says permission not found. I do "su" and it says the user does not have the permission? How do i do that? In File Explorer i tried "right click" and no use

Comment: You have to have the proper permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file. I believe it is android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Use adb shell rather than the terminal emulator - this will likely run with more capable permissions than a shell created by an app may, and is more likely to have a workable path

Comment: The adb command line is also a lot faster than opening ddms, or typing on the terminal emulator (assuming you have a pc available)

Answer (score 1):

If you're don't want to use Eclipse you can go to the folder where you have Android SDK. There you will find ddms.bat in tools folder. Later in menu click on Device -> File Explorer.

As far as i know DDMS has more features than Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Thanks - In DDMS i was able to open the directory, but how to remove it (not using code) directly on sd card

Comment: There is a SD card mounted as a directory and on the top you will find minus icon which allows to delete files. Of course only these which permission allows to.